# ubuntu 16.04LTS compile obfuscator-llvm

Tags: llvm

cmake version 3.5.1

ubuntu 16.04LTS

I want to compile llvm on ubuntu follow  [git wiki](https://github.com/obfuscator-llvm/obfuscator/wiki/Installation):

$ git clone -b llvm-4.0 https://github.com/obfuscator-llvm/obfuscator.git

$ mkdir build

$ cd build

$ cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ../obfuscator/

When I execute `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ../obfuscator/`,report ab error:

```
-- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_NO_NESTED_ANON_TYPES_FLAG
-- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_NO_NESTED_ANON_TYPES_FLAG - Failed
CMake Error at cmake/modules/AddLLVM.cmake:1163 (add_custom_target):
  add_custom_target cannot create target "check-llvm-bindings-ocaml" 
  because another target with the same name already exists.The 
  existing target is a custom target created in source directory 
  "/home/ryu/Ollvm/obfuscator/test". See documentation for policy 
  CMP0002 for more details.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/modules/AddLLVM.cmake:1226 (add_lit_target)
  test/CMakeLists.txt:150 (add_lit_testsuites)
```

I don't konw what check-llvm-bindings-ocaml is,and how cam I solve this problem? Can you help me? Thank you, thank you, thank you!!!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and the bellow command can solve it:

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release DLLVM_INCLUDE_TESTS=OFF
```

FYI:
https://github.com/obfuscator-llvm/obfuscator/issues/71

Comment: link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: THX. I provided the essential part---- the command in the answer. And this link is just for FYI~:)